# How to measure time difference in different frames of reference in relativity

Tags: special-relativity, reference-frames, time

I saw [this](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/502220/time-difference-as-a-result-of-lorentz-boost) post about measuring the time difference between two clocks and I couldn't understand Ajay Mohan's answer even after his edit.
I tried to draw a picture of what I think actually happens.
[image: Frames]

In the above picture the $S'$ frame is in red, the $S$ frame is in green and $C_1$ $C_2$ are the two clocks.
Since the clocks are synchronous in $S'$ then if I project their endpoints to $S'$, the values of $t'$ should match for both clocks, that is $t_1'=t_2'$. Here for simplicity I assumed that the $S$ observer (green) is just rotating with respect to $S'$.

Can you explain with a similar diagram why am I wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand your diagram, but if you have two clocks that are synchronised in S', then in general they will be unsynchronised in S if S is moving inertially relative to S'.

There are two different ways in which you can compare time intervals between the two frames. One is to compare the interval measured by a single clock in S' with the readings on two clocks it passes in S; in that case, the reading on the single clock in S' will be shorter than the difference in the readings of the two clocks it passes in S. The other way is the reciprocal arrangement in which two clocks in S' in turn pass a single clock in S, in which case the interval measured by the single clock in S will be less than the interval according to the two clocks in S'.

Comment: I understand that, the problem is that I think when we say that clocks are synchronous in $S'$ this means that $t_1'=t_2'$ while the correct answer is $t_1=t_2$.

Comment: I think you confusion stems from a misunderstanding of simultaneity. At a given moment of time in frame S, the time at A is the same as the time at B, so tA =tB. Likewise at a given moment in S' the time is the same at A and B, so t'A=t'B. The point you are missing is that a given moment in S is not a single given moment in S', and conversely a single given moment in S' is not a single given moment in S.

Comment: Is it possible that Ajay Mohan made a mistake in his answer, since he claims that $t_A=t_B$ and computes $t_A'$ and $t_B'$ but another person in the same post claims that the problem lies in the sign of velocity that o.p. chose and proceeds to compute $t_A$  and $t_B$ given that $t_A'=t_B'$. Which of the two is correct?

Comment: Both are correct! You can either pick an instant in S, when tA=tB, and calculate the difference between the values of t'A and t'B that correspond to tA=tB, or you can take an instant in S' when t'A=t'B and calculate the difference between the corresponding values of tA and tB. They are two different scenarios- it is not a case of one of them being right and the other wrong.

Comment: The key point is that in your reference frame, S, 'now' means a level slice through spacetime normal to your time axis. If I am in my frame S', then 'now' for me is a level slice through spacetime normal to my time axis. But since my time axis is tilted relative to yours, my 'now' is actually a sloping slice through time in your frame, and your 'now' is a sloping slice through time in my frame.

Comment: So you can look at the situation either from your perspective or from mine, and you will get two different answers depending on which perspective you take.